# Object reference error in NavigationService.Navigate

Tags: windows-phone-8

Inside my `MainPage` constructor I'm using `NavigationService` to navigate to another page, but I'm getting the error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Does anyone know why I'm not able to navigate from my constructor?

```
public MainPage()
    {           
      InitializeComponent();
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/test.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: The problem is solved when i use the NavigattionService in PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded instead. I am not sure this is the solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you're navigating to hasn't yet been created in the c'tor.  "Loaded" fires after the objects are all created, and is the right spot for doing things like navigating to another page and such.

Comment: Exactly, during the c'tor NavigaitonService is null because the page hasn't been navigated to yet. Using the "Loaded" event handler or the "OnNavigatedTo" method override is the way to go here. But why even navigate someone to a page that immediately navigates away?

Comment: Thanks for explaination.Naviation to the second page was dependent on some conditions. so it would stay on mainpage or navigate to an other

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but [from what MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (and mentioned by @JustinAngel's comment above), you should actually use the `OnNavigatedTo` event, rather than `Loaded`. While `Loaded` still works,

> Typically, you use the OnNavigatedTo method instead of creating an
>   event handler for the Loaded event. The OnNavigatedTo method is preferable because it is only called once for each time the page becomes active. The Silverlight framework raises the Loaded event each time the element is added to the visual tree, which potentially can happen more than once when activating a page.