# How to skip login page if the user data is saved in the isolatedstorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone 8 app that requires logging in.

When the user opens the app for the first time he login and his data is saved in the isolated storage, the next time he starts the app I check on his id in the isolated storage and try to navigate to the home page to skip the login page but it's not working.

Here is my code in the login page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings WasalnySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (WasalnySettings.Contains("CurrentUserGUID"))
    {
        string mydata = (string)WasalnySettings["CurrentUserGUID"];
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes, Nullexceptionhandler in the "NavigationService" Line

Comment: Can you add the full exception details to your question?

Comment: {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Project.MainPage..ctor()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it worked when I wrote the navigation line in the "onNavigatedTo" event handler

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // at this point, the page has been fully loaded:        
    IsolatedStorageSettings WasalnySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (WasalnySettings.Contains("CurrentUserGUID"))
    {
        string mydata = (string)WasalnySettings["CurrentUserGUID"];
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, good call. It even says in the documentation for `OnNavigatedTo`: *Typically, you use the OnNavigatedTo method instead of creating an event handler for the Loaded event.* This is better than my answer. Good find! Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the Home page hasn't loaded yet, as it wouldn't have yet since your call is in the constructor. Try handling the `Loaded` event and putting your `Navigate` call in there:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Assign the handler:
    MainPage.Loaded += CheckLogin;
}

void CheckLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // at this point, the page has been fully loaded:        
    IsolatedStorageSettings WasalnySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (WasalnySettings.Contains("CurrentUserGUID"))
    {
        string mydata = (string)WasalnySettings["CurrentUserGUID"];
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Found here: [Object reference error in NavigationService.Navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482544/object-reference-error-in-navigationservice-navigate)

Comment: The event 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Loaded' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: oops I think I have that backward in my pseudocode. check my updated answer. Should be `MainPage.Loaded += CheckLogin;`