# Windows phone not Navigating to other page

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8

In a windows phone 8 application, I am able to navigate from MainPage.xaml to other pages. But if I try to navigate from a page other than the MainPage.xaml, it is not navigating, and my app is breaking in the `RootFrame_NavigationFailed` Event in App.xaml.

For Example:

I am able to navigate from MainPage to Page1 and MainPage to Page2, **but not** Page1 to Page2.

This is what my code looks like:

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: If it works from MainPage to Page2, I don't see why it wouldn't from Page1 to Page2. In Page1, where are you calling the `NavigationService.Navigate` from? The page constructor, a specific event, a background thread, ... ? If you replace your line by `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`, does it work?

Comment: Are you performing the navigate event from a click or action or directly when the first page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling `Navigate` before the page you want to navigate to has loaded. Check out the answer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482544/object-reference-error-in-navigationservice-navigate).

Try moving your `Navigate` call to the `Loaded` event of your page.